# What is the correct rails association for two players having a match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have models for 'Player' and 'Match'.  Each Match record has two Players, one winner and one loser.

What would be a good Rails Active Record association for this?

```
Player
  name

Match
  winner_id (this is a player ID)
  loser_id (this is a player ID)
```

I will want to be able to get the win count for a player, and get all players that have never been in a match.

Comment: players has_many :matches.
matches belongs_to :winner, class_name: "Player"
belongs_to :looser, class_name: "Player" , maybe

Comment: If your question has been resolved, please select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do either

**Has one**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :winner, class_name: "Player", foreign_key: "winner_id"
  has_one :loser, class_name: "Player", foreign_key: "loser_id"
end
```

or, if you want to just update which is the winner/loser later, you could do something like

**Has many through**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players, through: :match_players

  # Pseudocode - not sure if this is the exact query you'd need, given players relies on the table which is being JOINed
  def winner
    players.joins(match_players: {winner: true}).load.first
  end
end
```

where your MatchPlayers join model/table will have defined some field identifying the winner/loser.

Yet another option with **Has many through**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many-source
    has_one :winner, through: :match_players, source: :player
    # etc.
end
```

You can do this a number of different ways, using different associations and ways to keep the data you require.

As for the Player model, that depends on what you want/need for your application. Let's suppose you use something like the third option. The player association of might look like

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :matches, through: :match_players
end
```

This is basic association design, I recommend you read the link at the bottom of my answer, as you'll need to decide which (if any) solution best fits your use case.

You'll need to decide which type of association best fits your use case. You can learn more at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: in your "has_one" example, what association goes in the "player" model?

Comment: Updated. Again, this is more of a design choice than anything. You'll have to make a decision for what works best for you.